# Processmaker Form Print button

Tags: processmaker

I'm using processmaker 3.0.1.7-community, I've added the Print button to the form. However, when I print using that button, a dropdown field does not display its value on the printout, but is correctly displayed on the form itself.

Weird enough, when I use the print functionality from the browser, the printout has the correct value displayed.

Used Internet Explorer, tried on Chrome same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug that was reported before when I was working in ProcessMaker. Have you tried upgrading to the latest version and see if it works?

I hope this helps.